# Can a mysql query return all of an entities fields in single row?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to setup schema  for buildings and all their info.

because the number of areas for a building can vary , I have stored the areas in a table "areas",
where each area has a foreign key pointing to the primary key of the building they belong to.

What I want is to try and get all the info for a building on one line like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
id |   address           | owner     | area 1  |  area 2   | area 3 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 21  kingsbridge  st | claudia   | kitchen |  bathroom |  garage|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using a `LEFT JOIN` I can get the info, just not in the format Im after

I have set up a schema here
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83558/6

was hoping there is a query like maybe an aggregator function like GROUP BY or something?
is this possible?

Comment: Why? Issues of data display are generally best left to application level code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select x.pId, x.address, x.owner,
      max(x.area1) A1, max(x.area2) A2,max(x.area3) A3,max(x.area4) A4,max(x.area5) A5
from 
(
SELECT p.id pId, p.address, p.owner, a.id aId, a.property_id, a.area_name,
        case when a.area_name = 'kitchen' then a.area_name else null end as area1,
        case when a.area_name = 'garage' then a.area_name else null end as area2,
        case when a.area_name = 'checkout' then a.area_name else null end as area3,
        case when a.area_name = 'booths' then a.area_name else null end as area4,
        case when a.area_name = 'bathroom' then a.area_name else null end as area5
FROM   properties p
       LEFT JOIN areas a
              ON p.id = a.property_id
  ) as X
        GROUP BY pId, x.address, x.owner
```

But you need to know what are the distinct areas.

Comment: nice one, that gives me enough to go off of, thanks!

Comment: @user4668401 hi this query can be a little simpler, there is no need for sub-query in FROM clause... Here take a look [HERE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83558/43) also there is another query which dynamically generate results (You don't need to know what are the distinct areas) GL!